# How to share my WAMP installation between two XP and Win7 on my pc?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, wamp

I have a dual boot system, meaning, I have both WinXP and Win7 installed on my system. I have installed WAMP server for testing and development purposes on my WinXP, and now I want to use the same installation from Win7 as well, so that I can work on same project no matter which OS I am currently using. Is this doable?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need install your alter OS on a virtual machine to use WAMP share setting. after run both win 7 on your system and win XP on virtual machine that installed on win 7 , you can run the WAMP SERVER as a real server for all of your OS.

Answer (score 0):

I would install WAMP on both OSs but move your website source code to something like Dropbox. Then your changes will be synced across both OSs.